# Using MPMoivePlayerController to play Youtube Video, but it doesn't work

Tags: youtube, rtsp

It is obvious that MPMoivePlayerController not support 3gp video, but the document said it supports.
Also does the RTSP protocol.
How to play Youtube Video, and when one movie finish, it will notify us to play next.
There is some example that play's Youtube by using UIWebView, but it can't catch the finished notification.
I use Xcode 4.3, meanwhile, the moiveplayer seems do well below xcode 4.2.